# Can't figure out why this trimming function won't work correctly

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4

===============================================================================

```
void trim(const char * orig, char * dest)
{
    size_t front = 0;
    size_t end = sizeof(orig) - 1;
    size_t counter = 0;
    char * tmp = null;

    if (sizeof(orig) > 0)
    {
        memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));

        /* Find the first non-space character */
        while (isspace(orig[front]))
        {
                front++;
        }
        /* Find the last non-space character */
        while (isspace(orig[end]))
        {
                end--;
        }

        tmp = strndup(orig + front, end - front + 1);
        strncpy(dest, tmp, sizeof(dest) - 1);
        free(tmp); //strndup automatically malloc space
    }
}
```

===============================================================================

I have a string:

**'     ABCDEF/G01        '**

The above function is supposed to remove the spaces and return to me:

**'ABCDEF/G01'**.

Instead, what I get back is:

**'ABCDEF/'**

Any ideas?

Note: the quotes are just to show you that spaces exist in the original string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strncpy` is wrong. `sizeof(dest)` is not what you want (it's the size of a pointer on your machine). You probably want: `end - front`. Instead, try:

```
memcpy(dest, front + start, end - front);
dest[end] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been beating myself up over this. I changed it to "end - front + 1" and it worked!! Of course, I'm checking that end - front + 1 is less than the max length I have for dest

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof(dest)` doesn't do what you think it does! It returns the size of the *pointer*, not the length of the string. You need to supply a maximum length of the destination to your function.

For the string `orig` you want to use the `strlen` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t end = sizeof(orig) - 1;
strncpy(dest, tmp, sizeof(dest) - 1);
```

You probably want strlen instead of sizeof here.

Answer (score 1):

```
void trim(const char * orig, char * dest)
{
    size_t front = 0;
    size_t end = sizeof(orig) - 1;
```

In that code, `sizeof(orig)` is the size of a pointer. All pointers are the same size, probably 8 in your implementation. What you want to use is `strlen(orig)` instead.

Comment: Am guessing OP has a 64 bit OS :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (it doesn't use temporary memory):

```
void trim(const char * orig, char * dest)
{
    size_t front = 0;
    size_t end = strlen(orig)-1;
    size_t counter = 0;

    *dest = '\0';

    if (strlen(orig) > 0)
    {    
        /* Find the first non-space character */
        while (front < end && isspace(orig[front]) )
        {
                front++;
        }
        /* Find the last non-space character */
        while (front < end && isspace(orig[end]))
        {
                end--;
        }

        counter = front;
        while ( counter <= end )
        {
                dest[counter-front] = orig[counter];
                counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Not tested!

Answer (score 0):

You must replace sizeof() to strlen() everywhere in your function.
Here is working edit:

```
void trim(const char * orig, char * dest)
{
    size_t front = 0;
    size_t end = strlen(orig)-1;
    size_t counter = 0;
    char * tmp = NULL;

    if (strlen(orig) > 0)
    {
        memset(dest, '\0', strlen(dest));

        /* Find the first non-space character */
        while (isspace(orig[front]))
        {
            front++;
        }
        /* Find the last non-space character */
        while (isspace(orig[end]))
        {
            end--;
        }

        tmp = strndup(orig + front, end - front + 1);
        strncpy(dest, tmp, strlen(dest));
        free(tmp); //strndup automatically malloc space
    }
}
```

(I've tested it)

Comment: The -1 is required to force it to end the destination with a '\0' null character.

Comment: I saw in debugger, that sizeof() for a string '     ABCDEF/G01        ' returns 7 insted of 10. %)